# jquery prepend element

Tags: jquery, dom, live, prepend

I have a list item which contains an anchor tag. This does X on click which is fine. However when i add in a new list item on the fly via jquery and then click the anchor tag within this new list item the click is not registered. Code snippets below.

**On click:**

```
$('ul#foo li p a#delete').click(function(){ 

alert('hmm');
});
```

**Adding new element after an ajax call:**

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, data){
            $('ul#foo').prepend(data.li);
        }
```

Now i think its to do with the fact that the DOM isnt aware of the new element?

So after some googling i realized everyone is saying use the .live() on 'change'

**So i tried .live():**

```
$('ul#foo').live('change', function() {
    //something
});
```

Thats where im stuck. ive never used .live() before. Am i missing something, am i doing it wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

What id like is for the click to be registered on my new on-the-fly element.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion you're having is with selectors actually.  Once you select the right thing through jQuery, the rest follows more easily.  Ok, so your html should look more like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="someUniqueClassToTheseLinks" href="whatever"></a></li>
</ul>
```

so that when you add an li through jQuery, it would look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="someUniqueClassToTheseLinks" href="whatever"></a></li>
    <li><a class="someUniqueClassToTheseLinks" href="whateverElse"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Now your live event registration is just:

```
$('a.someUniqueClassToTheseLinks').live('click', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `live` right, but I don't think you want the `'change'` event.  You should use `'click'` instead.  Also, rather then using the `ul#foo` selector, you'd want to go back to your original `ul#foo li p a#delete` selector.

Something like:

```
$('ul#foo li p a#delete').live('click', function(){ 

});
```

As Milimetric pointed out, this will have its own issues as well, due to the fact that your selector is using the `#id` selector type.  Element IDs must be unique on a page.  Really, you'd want to assign a css class to all elements that you want to catch with the click event handler and then change your selector accordingly.

Rather then `<a href="#" id="delete">`, you could do `<a href="#" class="delete">` and change your selector to `ul#foo li p a.delete`.

Comment: this won't work because #delete is an Id and there can't be more than one of them on the page.

Comment: A much better selector would just be `$('#delete')`. This will result in jQuery calling `document.getElementById` only once.

Comment: @Milimetric wow i missed that myself. i never usually do that. I forgot about the smarty foreach loop lol. thankss :) . Along with this and the live example below all if fixed and well.

Answer (score 1):

You want jQuery delegate().

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

It works similar to `.live` but it's a little easier and recommended over `.live` which is really only kept around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Cool! I learned something.  Here's a good article on .live vs .delegate: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html.  The main difference is that delegate can be chained